# Unit Testing Events in Laravel 8 throw EventFake::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher, null given

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to fake an event using Unit Testing, so no DB, no Application, just pure classes.

I'm following the documentation for Laravel 8, my current version, but I'm still getting the error

```
1) Tests\Unit\HandShake\ConfirmApplicationHandShakeActionTest::BasedOnAnExistentAppIConfirmTheHandShake
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Support\Testing\Fakes\EventFake::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher, null given, called in /Users/pablo/Workspace/xxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Event.php on line 38
```

As you can see is asking for an object implementing the interface Dispatch, my Event has the trait dispatch, but anyways here it says that I'm passing `null`

My Test code is the one as follow

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\HandShake;

use App\Actions\ConfirmApplicationHandShakeAction;
use App\Events\HandShakeReceivedEvent;
use App\Exceptions\NotFoundApplicationException;
use App\Models\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
use Mockery;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ConfirmApplicationHandShakeActionTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     *
     * @test
     * @throws NotFoundApplicationException
     */
    public function BasedOnAnExistentAppIConfirmTheHandShake()
    {

        $appName = 'testDummy';

        Event::fake([HandShakeReceivedEvent::class]);

        $applicationModel = Mockery::mock(Application::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('exists')
                ->andReturn(true)
                ->once();
        });
        $confirmation = new ConfirmApplicationHandShakeAction($applicationModel);
        $confirmation->execute($appName);
```

The Class that I'm testing is

```
    <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Actions;

use App\Events\HandShakeReceivedEvent;

use App\Exceptions\NotFoundApplicationException;
use App\Models\Application;


/**
 * Class ConfirmApplicationHandShakeAction
 * @package App\Actions
 */
class ConfirmApplicationHandShakeAction
{
    /**
     * @var Application
     */
    private $application;

    /**
     * ConfirmApplicationHandShakeAction constructor.
     * @param Application $application
     */
    public function __construct(Application $application)
    {
        $this->application = $application;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $appName
     * @throws NotFoundApplicationException
     */
    public function execute(string $appName)
    {

        if ( ! $this->application->exists($appName)) {
            throw new NotFoundApplicationException('The Application do not exists or is not active');
        }

        HandShakeReceivedEvent::dispatch($appName);
    }
}
```

Lastly the event is

```
    <?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class HandShakeReceivedEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Probably is one of those moments where I'm missing a stupid character, but I went through this error, and I cannot find the right solution.

**UPDATE**

I keep digging and I found that the getFacadeRoot() is returning null, so I'm assuming that something is not properly initialized, still not clue

static::swap($fake = new EventFake(static::getFacadeRoot(), $eventsToFake));

Thank you in advance if you find the issue or can point me in the right direction. I also tried FakeFor and Fake without sending the event as a parameter

Answer (score 10):

**Problem solved**

When you create the test files with artisan, for some reasons the `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` they use is the one in PHPUnit, but they should use the one in Laravel `Tests\TestCase`

Extending your tests with `Tests\TestCase`  will sort the problem